# Can't import xml to dataset if xmlnode has attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using the following codes to read xml file to a datagridview in c#:

```
newDataSet.ReadXml(filepath);
dataGridView3.DataSource = newDataSet;
dataGridView3.DataMember = "aaa";
```

And my xml file looks like this:

```
<root>
   <aaa>
      <Param_1>1</Param_1>
      <Param_1>2</Param_1>
      <Param_1>3</Param_1>
   </aaa>
</root>
```

I can read the xml to dataset without any problems. Then I added some
attributes to the `<Param>` nodes so it becomes

```
<Param_1 size="2">1</Param_1>
```

The dataset can't show any xml data, does anyone knows why?

Also if I change my xml file to something like:

```
<root>
   <Data_1>
    <Name>aaa</Name>
    <Params>
      <Param_1>1</Param_1>
      <Param_1>2</Param_1>
      <Param_1>3</Param_1>
    </Params>
   </Data_1>
</root>
```

Is there still possible to use DataSet method to read them into a datagridview or I have to use something like linq?

If I have to, can someone show me how to do that using linq?

Comment: for some reasons, the xml files doesn't show up right, I use "(" instead of "<" here for xml:
(root)

   (aaa)
      (param_1)1(param_1)
      (param_2)2(param_2)
   (/aaa)
(/root)

my code read the above xml ok. but not with the one with attribute:
(root)

   (aaa)
      (param_1 size="1")1(param_1)
      (param_2 size="2")2(param_2)
   (/aaa)
(/root)

The last xml example I want to do the following:
(root)
   (Data_1)
   (name)aaa(/name)
   (params)
      (param_1)1(param_1)
      (param_2)2(param_2)
   (/params)
   (Data_1)
(/root)

Comment: damn, just can't get it right...Sorry

Comment: you can get the angled brackets to show up in your original post by indenting each line by 4 (might be 3 or 5, do try) spaces. welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Select the text, then press Control-K.

Comment: your third XML blck is missing the closing </Data_1> element

Comment: Actually, the edit by John introduced a typo. If you look at the comment by Alex, there was `<Data_1>` tag instead of `<aaa>` in the edit. But it was without `/` - and this may or may not be the problem with xml file. I guess it was not, otherwise Alex would get the `XmlException`.

Comment: Actually, no. All I did was indent it. The typo is original.

Comment: Sorry, history doesn't show that. But history often skips some edits or joins them...

Comment: Now I can see - needed to look at the source.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read data to xml document and bind to it using XmlDataSource, and not DataSet. And verify that structure is correct for binding. Looking at your comment (not at the edit by John, but rather at the comment under you question, there is no `/` symbol which should be in the closing tag: `</Data_1>`.

Or change structure to any that you wish, provided that it suits you for binding. After that you can read data:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("XMLFile1.xml", XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

Regarding Linq: you can start from reading [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx). But anyway you should not create complex xml structure - making it complex adds you a lot of work to deal with it.

Comment: You can generate schema for your xml in Visual Studio (not in Express edition).

Comment: Anyway, to bind data you need a simpler structure, like in your first example. Or you will not be able to use binding correctly. Or you'll need to write your own binding code.

Comment: Actually, it also works without passing `XmlReadMode.InferSchema` parameter. To sum up: I suppose the problem is that you can't bind your complex data (in your last example), and not that dataset can't read it. Try to stop in debugger and look at dataset's content - you'll see that it loaded data in 3 separate tables, which is clearly not what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

DataSets are not a general-purpose mechanism for using XML. If the DataSet would not have produced the XML, then you cannot import that XML.

Comment: Wrong. They can, but not in general case.

Comment: Isn't that what I just said? The general case is "general-purpose ... XML". The general case does not work. What works is any XML that the DataSet could have generated. That does not include the case presented by the OP.